# Meteor: How to make two views - listing and article

Tags: javascript, meteor

What would be the best way in meteor for creating a template for using two different views? Let's call the template 'article' and by default there should be a list of all articles with an input field to create/add new elements. When selecting an article, the selected one should be displayed.

So right now what I am trying is this:

**package.js:**

```
Package.onUse(function(api){
    api.versionsFrom("METEOR@1.1.0.3");
    api.addFiles([
        'lib/client/templates/article.html',
    ], ['client']);
});
```

**router.js:**

```
Router.route('/article/:_id?', {
  name: 'article'
})
```

**templates/article.html:**

```
<template name="article">
    <form><input name="createNewArticle" type="text"></form>
    <ul><li>List of articles</li></ul>
</template>

<template name="article_detail">
    <p>Content of article</p>
</template>
```

Comment: *When selecting an article, the selected one should be displayed.* - You want your selected article to be displayed on the same page like: [http://ng-leaderboard.meteor.com/](http://ng-leaderboard.meteor.com/) or you want to be redirected to a new page?

Comment: Redirected to a new page. I know this is simple and basic, but I just don't know how to do that simple thing best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to redirect to a new page, make sure you have two separate routes (one for the list of all articles and another for the the single article or article detail)

**lib/router.js**

```
Router.route('/articles', {
  name: 'articles',
  waitOn: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('articles'),
    ];
  },
  data: function() {
     return {
       articles: Articles.find({})
     }
  }
});

Router.route('/article/:_id', {
  name: 'article',
  template: 'article',
  waitOn: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('article', this.params._id),
    ];
  },
  data: function () {
    return { 
       article: Articles.findOne({
        _id: this.params._id
      }) 
    };
  }
});
```

**client/templates/article.html:**

```
<template name="articles">
    <form><input name="createNewArticle" type="text"></form>
    <ul>
      {{#each articles}}
        <a href="{{pathFor 'article'}}"><li>{{title}}</li></a>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="article">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
</template>
```

Make sure you setup your publications too in `server/publications.js`

Comment: Would it be possible to use '/article' for showing the list and '/article/:_id' for showing the detailed article? Something like checking if there is an ID or not...

Comment: Yes it is. Just change '/articles' to '/article'

Comment: Thanks. Just the last question - even it is a little offTopic: How do I save a new element given by the input box to create a new article?

Comment: I don't know how your code looks like but it should be: `Template.articles.events({'submit form': function() { Articles.insert({title: $('#myfieldId')}); } });`